Testing a java jar that opens a shell app with integrated browser
I'm looking to create some automation tests for a java jar app, which opens a shell app with an integrated browser. The browser opens a web app, for which we have auto tests, but they cannot be ran for this shell app.
Does anyone have an idea how can I automate these tests?
Is python a good idea?
Selenium, cypress, playwright are working for the web apps itself, but cannot be used for shell apps.

You said that you can already test now that the browser indeed is opened. What else should exactly be tested?

behavior of the web app when it is run via java shell app.. the reason why we use shell is because we can prohibit any user input other then what we expect... so the functional behavior of the app is the same, but we need to test the same app via java shell as well..

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

But you wrote :  a web app, for which we have auto tests, so you can test the web app. Is the problem now only, how to invoke those auto tests from the shell? If so, you better describes these auto tests, i.e. what tools you are using.

I am using cypress for web app ui automation tests. I am not sure if it is possible to invoke those tests from the shell, because cypress is starting its own browser. So the main problem is, how to invoke those elements from the shell app, in order to manipulate them with auto tests?
